# Add two variables values in one variable with if else condition when data pass through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want  to add two variables(class textbox and hiddentxtbox) values in   one variable(check) by using if else condition and i want to pass that one variable(check)in  ajax.I want if someone select database headers options like firstname,lastname then the dropdown value is pass through checkbox else textbox value pass through checkbox.In my script i have pass the check variable like this:- 
 data: { check: textbox, oldval: textbox1,hiddentxtbox:hiddentxtbox,olddropval:textbox2}
As in above code only check variable has one value textbox.I want if someone select database headers options like firstname,lastname then the dropdown value is pass through checkbox like check:hiddentxtbox  else check:textbox

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){

    var  hiddentxtbox=[];
    var textbox = [];
    var textbox1 = [];
    var textbox2= [];

    var check = [];
    $('.check').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var current = $(this).val();

        //alert(current);
        textbox.push($(this).parents("tr").find(".textbox").val())
        textbox1.push($(this).parents("tr").find(".textbox1").val())
        textbox2.push($(this).parents("tr").find(".textbox2").val())
        hiddentxtbox.push($(this).parents("tr").find(".newhiddenBox").val())
      }
      check.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: 'practice.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {check: textbox, oldval: textbox1, hiddentxtbox: hiddentxtbox, olddropval: textbox2},
      success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>

      <table>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <select name='drop[]' class='select_drop textbox textbox1 form-control'>
              <option  value="firstname">firstname</option>
              <optgroup label='newtextfields' class='txtfields' >
                <option value='text' >text</option>
                <option value='number'>number</option>
              </optgroup>
              <optgroup label='database headers'> 
                <option value="firstname">firstname</option>
                <option value="lastname">lastname</option>
                <option value="email">email</option>
                }
              </optgroup>
          </td>

          <td><input  type='hidden' value='firstname'  class='textbox2  form-control' id='textbox2'></td>
          <td><input type='hidden' id='newhiddenBox' class='newhiddenBox' value='firstname'></td>
          <td><input type='checkbox'  name='check' value='firstname' class='check checkbox-primary' >Add Column</td> 
          <br>
          </select>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>


    <div class='form-group'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select name='drop[]' class='drop  form-control' >
              <optgroup selected label='newtextfields'>
                <option value='text'>text</option>
                <option value='number'>number</option>
              </optgroup>
              <optgroup label='database headers' class='hd'>
                <option value="firstname">firstname</option>
                <option value="lastname">lastname</option>
                <option value="email">email</option>
              </optgroup>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input  type='text' value='lastname'  class='textbox tt form-control' id='textbox'></td>
          <td><input  type='hidden' value='lastname'  class='textbox1 form-control' id='textbox1'></td>
          <td><input type='hidden' id='newhiddenBox'class='newhiddenBox' value='lastname'></td>  
          <td><input type='checkbox' name='check'  value='lastname' class='check checkbox-primary' style='margin-left:5px;'>Add Column</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='submit' >

</div>
```

Comment: create a string type variable and concatenate both variable by using separator. on the other side you can extract your data in diff variables.

Comment: yes i have added in code like this var co=[] , and then co= textbox + hiddentxtbox and alert that variable  in it.it alert modified value  and textbox value but i want only one value in check at a time.i want to do it by if else condition